# Get session in WebSocket server

Tags: php, session, websocket

I know this question has been asked before a couple of times. I followed the answers in those questions but the problem I'm facing remains.

Simply put, I want to get the username out of a session variable inside the WebSocket server. From what I understood, is that I need to get the session id and sent that over to the socket with each message. Using the id to read out the session.

Sending the session id: `this.socket.send('JOIN '+sessionID);`
I've made sure `sessionID` contains the correct id. This works fine.

This is the important part of the WebSocket server PHP:

```
<?php

$message = explode(' ', $message);
$command = array_shift($message);

if ($command == 'JOIN') {
    session_id(trim($message[0]));
    session_start();

    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
?>
```

The problem is, it still only works for the first user that joins the server. Any other user will be refused to connect because the username is already online.

Did I miss something?

Edit: I've made the server return `$message[0]` as well to make sure it's getting the correct session id and it returns what's expected. (It returns a different id for every user that tries to connect).

Comment: Close the session afterwards with [`session_write_close`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php)?

Comment: @gre_gor OMG that actually seems to have solved it! Please turn that comment into an answer. You've earned some rep with that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP keeps the sessions locked, to prevent concurrent writes, until the script ends or is manually closed with [`session_write_close`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php).

And because a WebSocket server is supposed run forever, you need to do it manually.